# Prove that $P(A \cap B\mid C)=P(A \mid (B \cap C))P(B\mid C)$

Tags: probability

I started with

$$P((A \cap B\mid C)=\frac{P((A \cap B)\cap C)}{P(C)}=\frac{P((A \cap C)\cap (B \cap C))}{P(C)}$$

by applying the basic property of conditional probability.

Then, I get stuck because I do not know how to come out with $P((A\mid B\cap C)$ and $P(B\mid C)$ from the above expression. I cannot think of any other possible multiplication rules that I can use. Please help!

Comment: I believe there is a mistake in your question. You are saying that $x = xy$ where $x = P(A \cap B|C)$. This is only true if $y=1$ which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Something is off with the question in your title. Check and edit.

Comment: The equation is likely to be  $P(A\cap B|C)=P(A|B\cap C) P(B|C)$.

Comment: You are right. Thank you for checking. I have corrected my errors.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are trying to prove is $P(A\cap B\mid C)=P(A\mid B\cap C)P(B\mid C)$
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(A\cap B|C)
&=&
\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(C)}\\
&=&
\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(C)} \frac{P(B\cap C)}{P(B\cap C)}\\
&=&
\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(B\cap C)} \frac{P(B\cap C)}{P(C)}\\
&=&
P(A|B\cap C)P(B|C)
\end{eqnarray*}